# how to store a large set of hotel availability data in a database

Tags: database, database-design, schema, database-schema

I currently have some 10.000 hotels (and growing) in a database. Currently no availability data is stored. I would like to store availability data + prices so people can search if a set of hotels (e.g. in New York) is available for a given date + duration.

What i have to store:

- 10.000 hotels (and growing)
- Per hotel 6 roomtypes
- Maximum of 365 departure days (but likely some less, say about 300)
- Each roomtype has about 30 durations (from 1 night to 31)
- 1 to 5 (but mostly 1-3) boardtypes (e.g. incl. breakfast, all inclusive)
- Each combination of the above has a price

When i would generate 1 "row" for each combination the number of "rows" will be 10.000 * 6 * 300 * 30 * 3 = 1.620.000.000 rows. As a start.

**Writing:**
A proximatly 25% of the data will be refreshed every day.

**Reading:**
20.000 visitors will search the data on a daily basis. Let's say there are 50.000 requests a day with a peak in the evening (20.000 between 8pm and 11pm). Mostly searching for 1 roomtype. Some will search for 2 roomtypes in 1 hotels. This last one is nice to have.

**Other requirements:**

- Each roomtype holds additonal information. That will be the maximum number of persons allowed in the room and a "room identifier" linking to other roominformation. Like facilities, photo's, description.
- Users should be able to use faceted search to filter in the dataset

My concrete question is how to setup the architecture of the database.

- My first thoughts where to just insert each combination. Resulting in a lot of records, growing quite fast when a hotel is added. Going to 100k hotels will result in 10 times more records. Structer like:

```
Hotelcode   Roomtypecode    Departureday        Duration    Boardcode   Price
H1234       R1234           20150701            1           A           35
H1234       R1234           20150701            1           B           45
H1234       R1234           20150701            2           A           65
H1234       R1234           20150701            2           B           80
H1234       R1234           etc                 etc         etc         etc
H1234       R1234           20150702            1           A           35
H1234       R1235           20150701            1           A           35
H1234       R1235           etc                 etc         etc         etc
H1235       R6554           20150701            1           A           35
H1235       R6554           etc                 etc         etc         etc
```

- Second thought was to "collapse" multiple records in to one. Possible when the price is the same. For example departure dates with the same roomtype/duration/lodgement data. Storing the departuredate like "20150701|20150702|etc". But then thought that a search as "is like '%20150718%' should be made. Which will be not very fast i think. Like:

```
Hotelcode   Roomtypecode    Departureday        Duration    Boardcode   Price
H1234       R1234           20150701|20150702   1           A           35
H1234       R1234           20150701            1           B           45
H1234       R1234           20150701            2           A           65
H1234       R1234           20150701            2           B           80
H1234       R1234           etc                 etc         etc         etc
H1234       R1235           20150701            1           A           35
H1234       R1235           etc                 etc         etc         etc
H1235       R6554           20150701            1           A           35
H1235       R6554           etc                 etc         etc         etc
```

"Basic" examples are the "hotel" variants of expedia.com, booking.com and orbitz.com. As you can see they are quite fast in returning results, also for "likely non cached results".

Concrete questions is "in what way should i structure this data in a database".

Of course i understand that the type of database (mysql, solr, Cassandra, redis) i choose will impact the results. At the moment i first want to find out the number of expected rows/documents that need to be stored.

**Update**

Based on the answer Livio Costea gave this would be idea 3. The difference with idea 2 is a) no hotel prices for the total stay but per night making it able to b) add multiple durations to a row.

```
Hotelcode   Roomtypecode    Departureday        Duration    Boardcode   Price
H1234       R1234           20150701|20150702   1|2         A           35
H1234       R1234           20150701            1|2         B           45
H1234       R1234           20150702            1|2         B           55
H1234       R1234           etc                 etc         etc         etc
H1234       R1235           20150701            1           A           35
H1234       R1235           etc                 etc         etc         etc
H1235       R6554           20150701            1           A           35
H1235       R6554           etc                 etc         etc         etc
```

An even smaller database will be possible when not adding the "duration" in a single column but just store the different "departuredays". If the departureday says 1-jan, 2-jan and 3-jan are possible. It can be interpreted that a stays for 1-jan + 3 nights is possible. I can imagine that asking the database for 3 nights of a specific roomtype and boardcode will be slower then the above described "idea 3". Next to that i'm struggeling with the idea of getting the right set of data when searching for 1 jan - 3 nights when 2-jan has a different price. In that case there will be 2 rows. One for 1-jan & 3-jan with price X and one for 2-jan with price Y. Those should then be combined on the fly. Might be that just storing more rows is more efficient.

I will store prices in a different database than all other information (hotelname, stars, etc), the roomtype key will be the match.

Comment: Instead of just storing a price for every combination, could you break it up into a structure with prices and/or coefficients per component?  Using your calculation, a single hotel will generate 162,000 rows.  Who's going to edit all those rows?  More likely, hotels have pricing and discount formulae.  Interview some hotel staff and learn how they handle it.

Comment: @reaanb what do you mean with "coefficients per component"? The 162k rows will not be edited manually. The hotel will save prices per roomtype and departure day. Difference is that they don't need a (fast) faceted search on it. That why i thought to flatten the data in a "pre-process", then it's faster to do a search on it. When i'm thinking completely wrong, let me know. Just one to learn :-)

Comment: By coefficients I mean multipliers, e.g. all inclusive board might add 10% to the basic room price instead of a fixed amount.  I recommend you don't denormalize this data - queries based on joining the aspects (hotel, roomtype, date, duration, board) can pre-filter those aspects before joining and use indices to speed up filtering and joining.  In contrast, a denormalized table's indices need to index all the multiple occurrences of the same value, and filtering occurs post-join which will be less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a lot of rows to store. If your price is as fragmented as you say then I would go for option 1 and because there are so many rows I would start thinking about sharding. The hotel code seems like a good candidate for a shard key. 
But I think that your prices are not that different for the same day. For example the price for 1 August will probably be the same even if you stay 5 or 8 days or even if you check in on 25 July or 27 July and so on. Probably the idea is to be able to store different prices for the same date based on check in and duration of stay, but most likely your prices will be the same in most cases. If it is like this better think of a structure where you have the price of the staying date without any duration and have additional rows only if your rate is changing based on duration and the date of check in. This should result in much less rows. 
Now for the persistence, if you want fast results you will need to add Redis to your stack, because the data is kept in ram which means it is very fast. You can go with all this schema in Redis, but because its a NoSQL you will have a lot of work to do if you will try to generate some reports for this data. Another option would be to add it as an additional persistence where you will keep your prices only and you will always make the search there. And you will have to keep it synchronized with a database where you keep all your stuff: prices and all other hotel and room information. This database can be a MongoDB or a SQL solution.

Comment: i updated my post based on your comments. Is this the way you tried to explain? As you can see in row 2 and 3 the price will be different for 1-july vs 2-july. Probably because 2-july is in a weekend. I need the duration because it might not be available for a specific check-in day. Regarding adding Redis to my stack i first thought was Cassandra, but i need to compare them more in depth.